# how to make button of same size in ionic

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to make button of same size (or same height).Actually I have four buttons and a toggle button in one row I need their height should same as shown in image .I need to  decrease height of toggle button .can we make same like that as show in image

here is my code

```
.margin_button_bar{
    margin-left: -0.5em!important;
  padding:0.5em!important;
}
.button_tab{
    position: relative;
}
.toggle_button{
    position: absolute!important; right: 0px!important;
    display: inline;
border: none;
    background: transparent;
  paddig:0.5em!important;
}
```

can we reduce toggle button height ?

Comment: Have you gotten your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the height of the toggle track (the part the toggle slides along) by chaning the .toggle .track {} class and you can change the handle (the part that moves) in the .toggle .handle {} class: or in your ion toggle you can just apply toggle-small as a class so it looks like `<ion-toggle class="toggle-small">`

see this play ground and play with the css http://play.ionic.io/app/46f56cb9e30d

code:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
       <ion-toggle ng-model="airplaneMode" toggle-class="toggle-calm">Airplane Mode</ion-toggle>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Styles here */
.toggle .track {
  height: 20px;
}

.toggle .handle {
  height: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```